# Django Rest + recurring calendar

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a rest api where I capture a start and end datetime (TimeField).
Now I would like to capture a recurring calendar: ie. Tuesdays 2pm to 4pm every 2 weeks.
is there an easy way to do this? something that would work easily with django rest framework?

thanks!!

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/josiahcarlson/parse-crontab ?

Comment: this is used for cron job. Im looking for a calendar that users will input from a web app.

Comment: It's actually a convenient format to store recurrences, which is what I thought your question was about. If you're looking for help in finding a web/js widget then you would first have to tell us why any of the existing ones don't work for you and why you can't create one from scratch, but then the question would probably be closed (help finding software/libraries are not a good fit for SO).